# Order Status only showing "Processing" option and no other

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Hi I found a strange error where under the order grid, I can only select "Processing" and not my other options, despite that I have at least 5 other optoins.  Here is a screen clip.

[image]

However I created a few options none of which are showing up.  Can anyone help?
Here are some of the order status options I have, all of which are not showing up except for Processing!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in magento only order status assign to particular state that only display in that dropdown,

it not display all the order status here

you can create other order status and assign it to any state https://meetanshi.d.pr/14uKCp